# setVisibilty() not working as expected

Tags: java, android

```
package com.anilkrishna.cricketscores;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView start;
    TextView credit;
    boolean flag=false;
    public void startApp()
    {
        start=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.animate().alpha(1).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(3000);
        credit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.credit);
        credit.animate().alpha(1).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(3000);
        credit.animate().alpha(1).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(2000);
        start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startApp();
    }
}
```

My requirement is that the app must display the textviews, animate and then disappear, but the animation is not happening and the TextViews are not visible once the app starts.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting start to GONE before it even has a chance to animate. Consider implementing Animation.AnimationListener on your Activity and then setting visibility in the onAnimationEnd method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.some_animation); 
    animation.setAnimationListener(this); 

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    start.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
     start.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE); 
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime, I used countDownTimers to manually set the animations. Can you please list the cons of going that way.